# how to populate html form fields using php from text file also delete specific form data

Tags: php, html, text

i have two php files

t1.php

```
    <form name="web_form" id="web_form" method="post" action="t2.php">
        <p><label>Enter name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
        <p><label>Enter email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></p>

         <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

t2.php [saves form data in text file]

```
 <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "a");
$savestring = $name . "," . $email . "\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
//echo “You data has been saved in a text fil”;
?>
```

and formdata.txt file

```
saish,saish@vk.com
rof,rof@vk.com
```

i want to display the form data from text file in a table and add [edit] and [delete] options beside them, and on clicking edit option the specific data must be automatically filled on seperate form "for example form3.php" and on clicking delete the specific data should be deleted. how can i do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a database? It would make your life somewhat easier.

Comment: yeah i thought of using database too but our internship sir wants to do it without a database. maybe he knew that using a database must be easier so he told us to do the "DIFFICULT" way.

Comment: We can't write this all for you (instead of you). Try to learn harder

Comment: you can write it for me but you wont (instead of me). Try to help harder

Comment: Okay, so someone is making you do it the hard way :D

Comment: We cannot give you an answer (that's not the point of Stack Overflow) but if I were to give a few pointers... think of your file as a poor man's database, so how best to store an editable data structure to a file? I would consider keeping your signups in an array format, that you can persist by serialising to the text file. Every time the page loads, read from the file and deserialise the array. If you assign some sort of unique key (e.g: unix timestamp) to every signup, it would be easier to identify individual entries to edit/delete.

Comment: To be clear - I'm only suggesting this approach as a means to meeting the requirements of this exercise. It's not a production grade solution in any way shape or form. Anyway, start by looking at [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: This might help to get you going. https://eval.in/1036857

Comment: Thanks alot man you helped me out alot